# Tomcat not recognizing the DLL files

Tags: java, windows, dll, tomcat5.5

i've an application which am trying to deploy in Window's Tomcat 5.5 - as an Axis Webservice. The application uses few DLL files, which I've placed the in the dir - $TOMCAT_HOME\common\endorsed\ and specified the same in the `java.library.path`.

But the DLL files are not recognized by the Tomcat. Following Exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no FCCJavaClientProxy in java.library.path
```

I also tried by putting the DLLs in a jar files..but no use.

Following is the batch file I created to start a Tomcat.

```
set CATALINA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_15\
set JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\common\endorsed;D:\TeamCenter\fms;
set FMS_HOME=D:\TeamCenter\fms
call tomcat5.exe
```

EDIT: I've created a separate batch file because, tomcat 5.5 does not have any batch files where I can set the above env variables or lib path

Answer (score 1):

How come you created your own batch file instead of using the startup.bat and catalina.bat that come with Tomcat? I would be willing to guess that invoking tomcat5.exe directly does not actually use the environment variables you are setting.

The best way to set custom environment variables is to add them to a file named `setenv.bat`  in the `bin` folder, Tomcat will invoke this script on startup or shutdown when you call `startup.bat`/`shutdown.bat`.

Comment: Tomcat 5.5 doesn't have any batch files...%TOMCAT_HOME%\bin has the following files - bootstrap.jar, commons-logging-api-1.1.1.jar, tomcat-juli.jar and tomcat5w.exe , tomcat5.exe

Comment: I guess I need to do something in bootstrap.jar

Comment: Worked for me. Just used instruction from http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/ and all my custom variables appeared in environment.